# Shadows that are pretty when rendered with eevee look wrong with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I am trying to render a donut.

This is my render with Eevee

[image]

This is my render with Cycles

[image]

The shadows in the left side of the donut are very odd since that is the side light is on. My render setting are:

[image]

I have tried without denoise, same thing. I will appreciate any help on how I can fix this. Thanks

Blend File
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QKYHmJjBYdekITTQbgccOBC2aTegfXY0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Added it, sorry

Comment: although i am not a shadow export, i would guess because your mesh looks a bit weird at these places...if you clean it up, it would look better:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRreN.jpg

Comment: weird because I don't see such a difference on my computer